# What encoding can be used to send the binary data to PHP?

Tags: android, network-programming

I am trying to send some binary data that is stored on the Android phone as a file to the web service that is created in PHP.

I have tried using `MultiPart` as well as `ValuePair` but no luck..!!

What I also did is to create a console application in Java, which reads the binary file from a static location on Windows and use the same PHP service and it works fine using `MultiPart`, below is the code for that:

```
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file,"text/plain");      
mpEntity.addPart("qLog", new StringBody(readFileAsString(file.getAbsolutePath()),
        Charset.defaultcharset)));
mpEntity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody(fileName));
mpEntity.addPart("personid", new StringBody(userid));
```

and the function `readFileAsString()` is:

```
private String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int numRead=0;
    while ((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1) {
        String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
        fileData.append(readData);
    }
    reader.close();

    return fileData.toString();
}
```

But when I do this on Android it is not maintaining the binary values. The reason I think is due to the default encoding in Android is UTF-8.

Can you please help here? How do I get the binary data sent from Android to PHP Service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`InputStreamBody`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/InputStreamBody.html) instead of `StringBody`:

```
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
mpEntity.addPart("qLog", new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file),
        file.getName());
mpEntity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody(fileName));
mpEntity.addPart("personid", new StringBody(userid));
```

---

*Edited*

Or you can use [`FileBody`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html) for more concise.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Tried both of them.. Still getting issues.